# Перевод цикла for из c++ в rust

Tags: c++, for, sfml, rust

Мне нужно портировать этот цикл for из c++:

```
for (int y = rect.top/BLOCK_SIZE; y < (rect.top + rect.height)/BLOCK_SIZE; y++)
    {
        for (int x = rect.left/BLOCK_SIZE; x < (rect.left + rect.width)/BLOCK_SIZE; x++)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

В rust. Я уже все перепробовал - и через range (то есть по нормальному, и через `..`, и через `..=`), и через цикл `while` - ничего не работает как надо.
Вот что у меня пока что есть:

```
for y in ((self.rect.top() / BLOCK_SIZE_F32) as i32)
            ..(((self.rect.top() + self.rect.h) / BLOCK_SIZE_F32) as i32)
{
    for x in ((self.rect.left() / BLOCK_SIZE_F32) as i32)
        ..(((self.rect.left() + self.rect.w) / BLOCK_SIZE_F32) as i32)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Суть проблемы в том, что цикл теряет нужные блоки. Если поменять `..` на `..=`, то наоборот, цикл пройдет лишние блоки.

В c++ rect - `sf::FloatRect`, в расте - `ggez::graphics::Rect`

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос информацию о том, что значит "не работает, как надо". Расскажите, как работает, как надо, и что не соответствует?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов >Суть проблемы в том, что цикл теряет нужные блоки. Если поменять .. на ..=, то наоборот, цикл пройдет лишние блоки.

Comment: я не знаю раст, поэтому вряд ли смогу Вам помочь. Если правильно понимаю, у Вас происходит преобразование типов.  Это не могло повлиять?

Comment: Я проверял, в c++ преобразования такие же, просто там они неявные. В расте они обязательно явные

Comment: я бы самое первое что сделал, так это вынес эти большие вычисления в отдельные переменные. Цикл явно стал бы выглядеть красивее. А там и ошибка станет видной. Если нет, то то же самое делаем с плюсовым кодом и получаем числа для сравнения.

Comment: Хм, я вынес вычисления в плюсах, там появилась та же ошибка, что и в расте. Видимо, "максимальная координата" должна быть типа float. Все таки с преобразованиями я разобрался не до конца

Comment: у выражения '(rect.top + rect.height)/BLOCK_SIZE' тип вещественный. А когда Вы его приводите к целому, я не знаю, что именно случится в расте.

Comment: Да, проблема была в этом. Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Все таки проблема была в преобразованиях. Как сказал @kovadim,

> у выражения '(rect.top + rect.height)/BLOCK_SIZE' тип вещественный

В итоге я поменял код на расте, теперь он выглядит так:

```
let mut y = (self.rect.top() / BLOCK_SIZE_F32) as i32;
let y_max = self.rect.bottom() / BLOCK_SIZE_F32;

let x_min = (self.rect.left() / BLOCK_SIZE_F32) as i32;
let x_max = self.rect.right() / BLOCK_SIZE_F32;

while (y as f32) < y_max
{
    let mut x = x_min;
            
    while (x as f32) < x_max
    {
        ...
        x += 1;
    }

    y += 1;
}
```

Comment: посмотрел на описания раста. там что, нормальных циклов нет?